# Why is git reflog expire not working

Tags: git

I want to get rid of some history in reflog. I tried

```
git reflog expire --expire=now
```

But nothing happened to the files in .git/ref/logs. What is the correct solution?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I finally found that `--all` has to be used to expire all reflogs.

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
```